# How can I compare two spreadsheets to see if column a is a match AND they overlap ranges =true?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two spreadsheets--one represents locations where the road was recently repaired and the second shows all eligible roads based on the road's speed limit.  The first spreadsheet has a list of ID's (Column B) and a beginning point (Column E) and ending point (Column F) for the repair location. The second spreadsheet may have multiple matches for each ID (Column A) and the eligible beginning points (Column P) and ending points (Column Q).

I want to compare to see if any portions of the eligible roads are already on the recently repaired list.

Completed repairs = 18SealCoatMap where B=Highway Name, E=Beginning Limit, and F=Ending Limit.

```
| County    | Highway   | BDFO   | EDFO   |  
|-----------|-----------|--------|--------|  
| Guadalupe | FM0078-KG | 13.064 | 14.018 |  
| Guadalupe | FM0078-KG | 14.018 | 14.848 |  
| Guadalupe | FM0078-KG | 14.848 | 18.991 |  
| Guadalupe | FM0465-KG | 0      | 3.342  |
```

Elibible repairs =MLOVER45 where A=Highway Name, B=Line ID, P=Beginning Limit, and F=Ending Limit.

```
| Lane      | ID | Highway | SpeedLimit | Begin_DFO | End_DFO |    
|-----------|----|---------|------------|-----------|---------|  
| FM0078-KG | 1  | FM0078  | 50         | 13.064    | 14.018  |  
| FM0078-KG | 2  | FM0078  | 55         | 14.845    | 14.848  |  
| FM0078-KG | 3  | FM0078  | 50         | 14.018    | 14.845  |  
| FM0078-KG | 4  | FM0078  | 55         | 14.848    | 15.006  |
```

So far, I'm only working with the beginning point of each eligible location. When I get a working formula, I'll copy it for the ending location.

Here's a more varied example... 
Eligible Locations:

`| Lane      | ID  | Highway | SpeedLimit | Begin_DFO | End_DFO |
|-----------|-----|---------|------------|-----------|---------|
| FM0791-KG | 369 | FM0791  | 70         | 0         | 6.909   |
| FM0791-KG | 372 | FM0791  | 70         | 6.909     | 18.603  |
| FM0791-KG | 377 | FM0791  | 55         | 19.286    | 19.486  |
| FM0791-KG | 378 | FM0791  | 70         | 19.486    | 30.971  |`

Completed Locations:

`| County   | Highway   | BDFO   | EDFO   |
|----------|-----------|--------|--------|
| Atascosa | FM0791-KG | 21.619 | 23.196 |
| Atascosa | FM0791-KG | 21.619 | 23.196 |
| McMullen | FM0791-KG | 0.000  | 7.017  |
| McMullen | FM0791-KG | 0.000  | 7.017  |
| McMullen | FM0791-KG | 2.190  | 2.760  |
| McMullen | FM0791-KG | 2.190  | 2.760  |`

I tried the following formula but every location came back true:

```
=IF(A2='18SealCoatMap'!B2:B345,AND(MLOVER45!P2>'18SealCoatMap'!E2:E345,MLOVER45!P2<'18SealCoatMap'!F2:F345),TRUE)
```

Then I tried:

```
=INDEX('18SealCoatMap'!B2:B345,MATCH(A2,IF(P2>'18SealCoatMap'!E2:E345,P2<'18SealCoatMap'!F2:F345)),2)
```

but all of the results came back `#N/A`

I expect the outcome to be the ID number for the eligible location (or TRUE) if there's a match so that I can schedule repairs for all locations that do not already fall within the limits. Based on the results, I will then schedule locations that are entirely or partially due for repair.

Comment: Please rearrange your sample data. Use some markdown tool like [this one](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). To me it's looking like your ID's are not the same over your two sheets, so no match = `#N/A` error!

Comment: Thank you...I updated the ID's to match but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you rework the first set of sample data, please. I think something has gone wrong with EDFO.

Comment: I have updated the first set of sample data.  Also... I have tried: 
 =INDEX('18SealCoatMap'!A1:I345,MATCH(A2,'18SealCoatMap'!B:B(IF(AND(P2<='18SealCoatMap'!F:F,P2>='18SealCoatMap'!E:E),"Done","NotDone"),0),2))  but I get a #REF! error

Comment: from the example.. which line in each table should get true (overlaping) and which one should get false (no-overlap) ?